# My laptop won't boot after adding RAM

Tags: linux, windows-8, memory

I have a problem with my HP dv6 laptop, which has dual boot Win 8 and Ubuntu.  It came with 4 GB RAM (one stick), and I added an 8GB stick.

When I try to boot to Win 8, it gives me BSOD,

> Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We're just collecting some error info, and then we'll restart for you.

But when I boot to Linux, it works perfect.

I ran memtest86 and after about 3 seconds, it just reboots itself.  All I can catch is the word "Unexpected" before rebooting.

I tried swapping the RAM but got the same result.  I tested the 8GB stick in another Dell laptop and it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you remove the RAM? What happens when you run memtest86 across all the RAM? What exact BSOD do you get?

Comment: about BSOD ' your pc run into a problem and need to ..'
when i run memtest86 i get ' Unexpect ' and my laptop reboot after 3 sec.

Comment: You have provided nowhere near the information needed to diagnose the problem. I asked for specifics about the BSOD and a description of what happens when you run memtest86, and you have provided neither.

Comment: This looks like you might have posted a "me too" answer and were advised to re-post as a question.  You're in the right place, but this lacks any context of the previous thread, so you need to make your question self-contained.  By dv6, do you mean the HP notebook?  What is the total RAM?  Have you tried swapping the RAM in each socket?  How many sockets are there and what size RAM do you have in each one?

Comment: Have you tried the newe 8 GB DIMM in the HP laptop by itself? 
Are you sure the laptop doesn't require equal-sized DIMMs?

Comment: Please post your HP Product number or the complete model number.

Comment: Jamie Hanrahan - it works fine in ubuntu.
 Algorithm Breaker - HP dv6-2125el

Comment: Likely ubuntu is using a small fraction of the total memory, and just hasn't had the problem *yet*.  Try a kernel compile.

Comment: Precisely. It might be as trivial as windows starting default allocation from the top of the memory and Linux from the bottom.